# ConcurrentModificationException when I do a addAll for a Set

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I get a concurrentModificationException at `allStates.addAll(states)` in the code below. How can I avoid this?

```
public synchronized Set<String> getAllStates(String clientName, Map<String, Set<String>> allClientStates) {
    Set<String> allStates = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
    final Set<String> keySet = allClientStates.keySet();
    for(String key: keySet) {
      Set<String> states = allClientStates.get(key);
      if(states != null)
        allStates.addAll(states);
    }
    return allStates;
  }
```

This is the top of the stacktrace

```
exception": "null\njava.util.ConcurrentModificationException\n\tat java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(HashMap.java:1445)\n\tat java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:1469)\n\tat java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:343)\n\tat com.xxx.config.ClientDashboardConfig.getAllStates(ClientDashboardConfig.java:312)
```

Comment: You seem to be modifying the map elsewhere. Note also that there doesn't seem to be a reason for using the keys at all: `allClientStates.valueSet().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(toSet())`.

Comment: Try using a basic `Set` type, like `HashSet` instead of `ConcurrentSkipListSet`. Methinks part of the issue is that the code is running too fast, and you have more than one `allAll` method executing at the same time on the object. A `HashSet` should resolve the issue.

Comment: This project is using Java 8, hence I have updated the piece with this code ```allClientStates.values()
.stream()
.flatMap(Set::stream)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());```

Comment: Hey man, if my answer solved your problem, go ahead and accept it. This site runs on volunteer effort, least you can do is appreciate people's time.

Comment: Still getting the concurrentModificationException exception after making the above changes.

Comment: Getting `entrySet()` instead of `keySet()` solves the issue. In the question I was trying to iterate the keySet and then get value from it, which was causing the exception.

Comment: Even using entrySet() didn't help the cause, still getting the same exception.

Comment: The concurrentModificationException was happening at `allStates.addAll(states);`. So I just added the local variable `allStates` in a Synchronized block like this ```synchronized (allStates) {} ``` and did all the transaction with it inside that block.

Answer (score 2):

```
allClientStates.values().stream()
    .flatMap(keys -> keys.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I still get  ConcurrentModificatinoException after modifying code to ```The current answers don't solve the problem. I changed my code to ```    Set<String> allStates = allClientStates.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
``` and I still get the exception ````

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why do you need the ConcurrentSkipListSet and the clientName. Is this code complete?

Also not clear if there's JVM version limitation

Using java 8 you can do like this:

```
allClientStates.values()
.stream()
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I was experimenting and also removed some other unrelated code from this function before I posted. Hence you see ConcurrentSkipListSet and an unused param. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I still get  ConcurrentModificatinoException after modifying code to ```The current answers don't solve the problem. I changed my code to ```    Set<String> allStates = allClientStates.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
``` and I still get the exception ````

Comment: @DeepakGopal can you please provide a parameter example so I can reproduce the issue?

Comment: ```    final Set<Map.Entry<String, Set<String>>> entrySet = allClientStates.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> key: entrySet) {
      Set<String> states = key.getValue();
      if(states != null)
        allStates.addAll(states);
    }``` This solves the problem. Thanks for the help @GuilhermeBrabo